# Stuck in deletion node in BST when node has both left and right child

Tags: binary-search-tree

I'm trying to understand the concept of deletion node in BST when node has both left and right child, but I'm a bit confused, because different books and other sources like web has different definition of this one.

Well, in my case, the Data are:
150, 100, 200, 80, 120, 110, 130, 170, 220

So, the tree is something like this:

```
       150
    /       \
  100        200
 / \         /  \
80   120   170   220
    /   \
   110   130
```

Okay. I'm going to delete node 100. I read somewhere that there are two way to do this. Choose either its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node. Well, if I choose in-order predecessor, the tree look like this :

```
       150
    /       \
  80        200
   \         /  \
   120   170   220
  /   \
 110   130
```

In this case the postorder traversal is:
110, 130, 120, 80, 170, 220, 200, 150
And its true.

But the second way that there its where I'm stuck is choosing in-order successor, in this case, we have:

```
       150
    /       \
  110        200
 / \         /  \
80   120   170   220
        \
        130
```

In this case the postorder traversal is:
80, 130, 120, 110, 170, 220, 200, 150
And its seems to be true, but in the book wrote that its not true. I've google it too much but everywhere write different approach to do this. Maybe all approaches are one, but i did not get it. Someone can explain it in a nutshell ?

I'm not looking for programing code. I'm just want to know what must do exactly?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"but in the book wrote that its not true"*: can you quote the book, so we can make sure for ourselves what they are saying is consistent or not?

Comment: The same set of values can (usually) be represented in more than one valid BST.  Any book that says your last picture isn't a BST is wrong.